# Intuitively, why is $H_n(X,x_0)\cong H_n(X)$ for $n\geq 1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm having a little trouble seeing how this is the case, just geometrically. This requires considering the chain groups $C_n(X,x_0)$ and $C_n(X)$. The former group is freely generated by everything in $C_n(X)$, except for the map that takes an entire $n$-simplex to $x_0$. The homology groups $H_n(X,x_0)$ and $H_n(X)$ would be the same, I believe, if that map is quotiented away, i.e., if it is a boundary of another map. But it appears to me that when $n$ is even, it is difficult to see that this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether there is an absolutely *intuitive* proof. You can do it most easily by considering the long exact sequence of homology groups of the pair $(X,\{x_0\})$.

As you say, the chain group $C_n(X,\{x_0\})$ can be regarded as the free abelian group generated by all singular $n$-simplices in $X$ except the constant map $\sigma^n_0$ with value $x_0$. Now look at $C_n(X)$.

If $n$ is odd, we have $\partial \sigma^n_0 = 0$, i.e. $\sigma^n_0$ is a cycle. It is easy to see that $\partial \sigma^{n+1}_0 = \sigma^n_0$, i.e. $\sigma^n_0$ is a boundary.

If $n$ is even, we have $\partial \sigma^n_0 = \sigma^{n-1}_0$, i.e. $\sigma^n_0$ is not a cycle. Thus there is no need to exhibit it as a boundary. However,  $\sigma^n_0$ may occur in a cycle $\zeta =  a_0\sigma^n_0 + \sum_{i=1}^r a_i \sigma^n_i$. I find it difficult to see what this means, and whether this is possible at all, and if so, whether $\zeta$ is homologous to a cycle without a $\sigma^n_0$-component. The latter is certainly true, but its proof would involve very formal arguments.